# Integral: how can I substitute a expression

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the integral

$$ \int \frac {x} {2 + \tan x} \, dx $$

Using the substitution

$$ t = \tan x $$

So it's ok to substitute $\tan x$ but when I get to substitute $dx$ obtain:

$$ dx = \cos^2(x) \, dt $$

Now how can I eliminate $$ \cos^2(x) \text{ ?}$$

Thanks

Comment: i think no elementar primitive function exists

Comment: @GrangerObliviate Are you just trying to change the integration variable to t, or actually find an antiderivative? Because as it has been pointed out, an elementary primitive doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\tan^2 x + 1=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x} + \frac{\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$$

Comment: how does this help to find the integral?

Comment: @math635 OP asks how to eliminate $\cos^2 x$ and this shows how to express it in terms of $t$.

Comment: ok thats true, although i don't see how from this we can easily evaluate the integral...

Comment: @math635 neither do I, in fact Wolfram Alpha spits gibberish http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28x%2F%282%2Btan+x%29%29dx

Answer (score 2):

Notice, if you let $$t=\tan x$$
$$\implies dt= \sec^2x\ dx=(1+\tan^2 x)\ dx=(1+t^2)\ dx$$ $$dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\tan(x) = t$, then $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$.

You may use $\tan^2(x) + 1 = \sec^2(x)$ to get the above.

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$or $\pm\sqrt{1+t^2}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy True. Although in his case hes has $\cos^2(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$dx=\cos^2(x)\ dt$$$$=\frac{dt}{\sec^2 (x)}$$$$=\frac{dt}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$ setting $\tan (x)=t$,  $$dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$